# when i try to make a post request it only returns the created date and the objectID

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
    when ever i make a post request it returns only the created date and the objectID
```

when ever i make a post request it returns only the created date and the objectID
   when ever i make a post request it returns only the created date and the objectID
   when ever i make a post request it returns only the created date and the objectID

```
    i tried testing it with postman but it was the same thing


    //this is the controller for creating a new room

   exports.create_a_room = function(req, res) {
      let new_room = new Room(req.body);
      new_room.save(function(err, task) {
        if (err) res.send(err);//testing for errors
        res.json(task);
      });
    };   

    //this is the schema for the Rest api.the created date is the the only one working

    var RoomSchema = new Schema({
        full_name: {//for full name
            type: String,
            Required: 'Enter first name'
        },
        time: {//for time
            type: String,
            Required: 'Enter checkout'
        },
        people: {//for people
            type: Number,
            Required: 'Enter people'
        },
        kids: {for kids
            type: Number,
            Required: 'Enter kids'
        },
        room_type: {//for room types
            type: String,
            Required: 'Enter room type'
        },
        room_number: {//for room number
            type: Number,
            Required: 'Enter room Number'
        },
        Created_date: {for created date.this is the only part of the schema that is actually working
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
    });

    it just returns the created date and the objectID generated by mongodb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Mongoose with MongoDB? Because you seem to have a bad schema. Replace all rows with "Required: ...", such as:

```
Required: 'Enter first name'
```

with:

```
required: true
```

(pay attention to the casing - the first letter is lowercased in "required")

See more here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required

Comment: Glad to hear that! If you feel your question was fully answered, you can also mark the answer as accepted. Thanks and good luck! :)